# MySQL syntax for CONCAT depending same table column?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, string-concatenation

This is my table :

| pkey | Name | Report_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | abc | 12 |
| 12 | def | 13 |
| 13 | sdf | 11 |
| 14 | dfg |  |

I want the ouput like :

| Name | Report_to |
| --- | --- |
| abc | def |
| def | sdf |
| sdf | abc |
| dfg |  |

I have tried this :

`` SELECT CONCAT( CASE WHEN `Report_TO` = `PKEY` THEN Name ELSE CONCAT( "no one " ) END ) ``

Now i get output as :

| Name | Report_to |
| --- | --- |
| abc | no one |
| def | no one |
| sdf | no one |
| dfg | no one |

Is it possible to get the output as i wished.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: You want a _self (left) join_, no concat.

Comment: i'm using mysql @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join table to itself and use left join to select desired columns:

```
    select tbl1.name , tbl2.name  from docs tbl1 
left join  docs tbl2 on tbl1.report_to = tbl2.pkey
```

---

Note: replace table_name with your tables actual name :

`table_name`  --> `your tables name`

sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c451e5/1/0)

Comment: there is no tbl2, i have only one table @aliFidanli

Comment: @eggyal you are right. i fixed it

Comment: @sai its alias name,  not table name. can you try it? it should be ok

Comment: Also, the desired output shown in the question would require reversing either the order of the selected columns or the logic of the join predicate.  Currently you're showing `reportee, reporter` not `reporter, reportee`.

Answer (score 1):

You can *join* multiple copies of the same table to itself, but in order to distinguish each such copy within your query all (but at most one) must be given some other, unique, *alias* by which to be known within the query.

Because you still want to include `dfg` in the output even though there is no-one to whom they report, you require an *outer join*.  There are two types of outer join, left and right, which indicate from which side of the join records should still be included even if the join predicate is not matched.

Therefore, you can use either ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c238/1/0)):

```
SELECT     reporter.Name AS Reporter, reportee.Name AS Reportee
FROM       my_table AS reporter
LEFT JOIN  my_table AS reportee
        ON reportee.pkey = reporter.Report_to
ORDER BY   reporter.pkey
```

or ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c238/1/1))

```
SELECT     reporter.Name AS Reporter, reportee.Name AS Reportee
FROM       my_table AS reportee
RIGHT JOIN my_table AS reporter
        ON reportee.pkey = reporter.Report_to
ORDER BY   reporter.pkey
```

Jeff Atwood (who co-founded Stack Overflow) wrote an excellent blog post that may be of interest to you, [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).